# Django valid XSS attack example

Tags: django, xss, cross-site

I found Django is pretty powerful to handle XSS attacks, I just wrote a simple textfield form, at template, xss_form.html:

```
<html>
<head><title>XSS Forms</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% if query %}
    Query: {{query}} <br/>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

And in view.py:

```
def xss1(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q'] 
        return render(request, 'xss_form.html', {'query': q})
    return render(request, 'xss_form.html')
```

So does everyone know some scripts input at the textfield box, can let the browser pop out an alert box ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you still have problem, look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping
Django should automaticly escape html code, unless you tell not to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following GET request:

`Something <script>alert("This is not secure")</script>`

You just need to modify xss_form.html from: 
Query: {{query}} ----> Query: {{query|safe}} 
It should look

```
<html>
<head><title>XSS Forms</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% if query %}
    Query: {{query|safe}} <br/>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```